# How do I populate the values of form fields with data from another page?

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert variables from an SQL result into a HTML form in a way that the user can open a form and auto populate the values based on selected data.

I am displaying a table with query results, I'd like the user to be able to open a form that populates certain fields with data from a link in the table row.

This is what I have so far:

```
  <?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE username = '$user_name' order by id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['group_name'] .  " "  . $group_numbers = $row['group_numbers'] = '<a href="myaccount_group.php">Click here to insert numbers</a>'  . '<br/><br/>';

  ?>
```

I was then going to try and pick up the POST variable on `account_group.php` and then insert the numbers into form fields when opened.

Basically, I need a way to list all of the groups which contain numbers, and then have the ability to select which group of numbers you want to use (so to add them to the form).

Comment: You have two closing tags for `</textarea>` but no opening tags? Besides that, I can't understand what you're trying to do, try [rewording your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8961860/edit).

Comment: Display each row of a table with an option to insert the row into a text field.

Comment: It's not clear what you're having trouble with and your code doesn't make sense even on a basic level. If you need to make clarifications, [edit] the post.

Comment: This question really doesn't make much sense at all. Remember, we have no concept of what you're trying to do, so you need to provide that. Telling us what you'd ultimately like to happen would go a long way. I _think_ I was able to understand what you want, but I strongly suggest editing for clarity.

Comment: I have edited the original post, however what i am trying to achieve is retrieving the results of a SQL table, where these are then displayed in a list, next to each row of result i want a button which will select this row and insert it into a form, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your question isn't really clear, I think I understand what you're trying to do, which is make links in a table that open a page with a form, having some fields preset by the values that you chose when clicking the link.

To do this is simple, just encode the values from your query in the links after they are displayed. E.g:

```
<a href="/form.php?field1=foo&field2=bar">Click here to insert numbers</a>
```

Then have `form.php` pick up the GET variables:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['field1']) ? $_GET['field1'] : '';?>">
```

I would recommend iterating over GET variables that `form.php` expects to check them for sanity and set friendly variable names. E.g. `$_GET['foo']` once confirmed set and checked for special characters and stuff could just become `$foo`.

You could also store them in the session for easy retrieval later. Note also that you'll want to make sure your links are properly encoded (via `urlencode()` when displaying the links, and `urldecode()` when consuming the variables in the form page).

This could be done with POST if you wanted, or lots of other ways. I suggested GET because it would be the simplest to implement.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i trying to do, however it was hard to explain. Although i am still having some trouble placing the row variable as 'field1' so '<a href="/myaccount_group.php?field1= . $group_numbers . ">Click here to insert numbers</a>'

Comment: Hmm, what would probably make that simple is to build a function that took an array as it's arguments, which built the link for you. You could then pass the current row (from your results) as the argument. It could return the whole formatted HTML link, or just what has to go inside of `href`. Again, don't forget urlencode().